# How to combine the two request in which one give response for another api key which pass for request

Tags: android

I want to parse two api at the same time in which one api get a response of key that key has api link and pass in another StringRequest forget response.

This is my function for parsing in which I want to parse firstly one api and get a response in response **href** name of key use for another api parse link.
please help me as soon as.
I searched and I got this link but it is not proper code.
https://www.versti.eu/TranslateProxy/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/37584001/how-to-combine-the-two-request-url-from-json-to-get-output-in-volley

```
private void parseSmartPhone()
 {
  StringRequest stringRequest= new                              
  StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, 
                Config.HOMECTEGORY, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                //getting the whole json Array from the response
                //   JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                mylist=new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0;i<=2;i++)
                {
                    latestsphone= new LatestSmartPhoneModel();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject objtitle=jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");

                    title=objtitle.getString("rendered");

                    objtitle=jsonObject.getJSONObject("_links");

                    JSONArray imgJsonArray=objtitle.getJSONArray("wp:featuredmedia");

                    JSONObject objJsonImg=imgJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    StringRequest request1= new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET,objJsonImg.getString("href"), new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONObject imggild=jsonObject.getJSONObject("guid");
                                String rendered=imggild.getString("rendered");

                                latestsphone.setLink(rendered);
                                latestsphone.setTitle(title);
                                mylist.add(latestsphone);


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });

                    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                    requestQueue.add(request1);
                    request1.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


                }

                UpcomingAdapter imgAdapter=new UpcomingAdapter(getActivity(),mylist);
                recyclerUpcoming.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
                recyclerUpcoming.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2));
                recyclerUpcoming.setHasFixedSize(true);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

}
```

Comment: Add second request on the successful response onResponse()  of first request

Answer (score 0):

This is your proper code, i corrected your posted code, Use these as global parameter.

```
ArrayList<LatestSmartPhoneModel> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

String title,link;     

private void parseSmartPhone() {

    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, Config.HOMECTEGORY, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                //getting the whole json Array from the response
                //   JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                    if (i==3)
                    {
                        i=4;
                    }
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject objtitle = jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");

                    title = objtitle.getString("rendered");
                    link=jsonObject.getString("link");
                    objtitle = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_links");
                    final LatestSmartPhoneModel latestsphone = new LatestSmartPhoneModel();
                    latestsphone.setTitle(title);
                    latestsphone.setLink(link);

                    JSONArray imgJsonArray = objtitle.getJSONArray("wp:featuredmedia");

                    JSONObject objJsonImg = imgJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    StringRequest request1 = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, objJsonImg.getString("href"), new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {


                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONObject imggild = jsonObject.getJSONObject("guid");
                                String rendered = imggild.getString("rendered");

                                latestsphone.set_links(rendered);

                                mylist.add(latestsphone);

                                UpcomingAdapter imgAdapter = new UpcomingAdapter(getActivity(), mylist);

                                recyclerUpcoming.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
                                recyclerUpcoming.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
                                recyclerUpcoming.setHasFixedSize(true);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(request1);
                    request1.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

}
```